# Export to Java application deletes files

Tags: anylogic

When I wanted to export the model I was working on as a Java application, I encountered an error regarding the databases I loaded into the model. When I said OK to the error, I realized that all the files in the folder I wanted to create the Java application were deleted. That folder was desktop by the way.

Right now all the files (i mean all of them!) on my desktop are deleted and they don't even show up in the recycle bin. How are we going to solve this situation? How can AnyLogic have the authority to delete all files in that folder? How is this authority not shared with me and not warned beforehand?

Comment: Sorry to hear, always good to work with Git or some other backup mechanism... Anyway, what was the error? Very hard to comment without that ;) What about the files in the model folder that you were trying to compile from? There is a "database" subfolder in each model folder...

Answer (score 0):

When you work with software in general, you need to have a version control in place that will allow you to recover your information. These problems occur, and if AnyLogic has access to your computer it's because you grant the permission and it needs the permission. If you make your desktop your project folder, then i would say you are to blame.. why would you do that...

Using GIT as Ben commented, is always a good idea... but it requires you to be conscious about when you commit a version.

What I do, is I use dropbox and all my projects are done in a dropbox folder... the good thing is that dropbox always saves automatically all the files on the folder... this has saved my life multiple times and I suggest you to do something like that in the future. So on one hand you have the autosaving features, which is useful, but sometimes you erase everything by mistake, and the autosave is not useful, but dropbox saves no matter what.